# if and else statement just not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

Here is my if statement. I'm trying to have two differnt options. One is if the user is logged in and the other of course if they're not.
For the life of me I can not get these to work. This is a Word Press site.. Any help here would be awesome. Here is what I have.

```
<div class="btn btn-success">
        <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a>           
    } else { 
        <?php add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false ); ?><?php endif; } ?>            
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you receiving an exception?  Or is it just not evaluating as you would expect?

Comment: You have bad syntax.  Your else statement is outside of php tags.

Comment: All I get is the white screen with any of the below code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <div class="btn btn-success">
        <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a>           
     <? else: ?>
        <?php add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false ); ?><?php endif; ?>            
            </div>
```

You have completely wrong syntax. Your `} else {` isn't even in PHP tags and the [alternative](http://php.net/alternative_syntax) syntax that you are using doesn't require braces.

Comment: Mixing `<?` (short tags) and `<?php` syntax is not that wise either.

Comment: Although your code didn't work it did send me in the right direction and I thank you and the rest for the big help..

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing [the two variations of `if`](http://php.net/alternative_syntax), even though:

> Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported.

It can either be

```
if (condition) :
    ...
else :
    ...
endif;
```

or

```
if (condition) {
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}
```

Choose one and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You start the `if` structure with `':'` ..then you change it to `'{'` or `'}'`
Read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php, for more information.

**Here is a solution:**

```
<div class="btn btn-success">
     <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): //start condition ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a>           
     <?php else: // else ?>
        <?php add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false ); ?>
      <?php endif; //close 'if' condition ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot mix syntaxes, so you cannot mix the colon and the curly braces.
- Your logic seems to be wrong. I don't use WordPress but I would think that `is_user_logged_in()` would return `true` for a logged in user.
- You are using php opening and closing tags in the wrong places.

So it would be something like:

```
<?php
if( is_user_logged_in() ):
?> 
    <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a>
<?php
else:   
    add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false );
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without : behind your if.

And you're missing a beginning `{` behind your if, because you got a closing one.

And you don't need an `endif;` because the closing `}` from else part will end the if.

```
<div class="btn btn-success">
        <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()) { ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a>           
    <?php } else { 
       add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false ); 
    } ?>            
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a>           
    else : 
        <?php add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false ); ?><?php endif; >            
            </div>
```

If your statement is used with `:`, you cannot use braces.

Correct ways:

```
if {} else {} 

if :  else : endif ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad syntax.
change:

```
} else {
```

to

```
<?php else : ?>
```

However, it would be better to rewrite the whole thing:

```
<?php
$btn = '<div class="btn btn-success">';
if(is_user_logged_in() !== true) {
   //logic here
   $btn .= '<a href="blahblah...';
} else {
 //else logic here
   $btn .= 'blah blah, else logic here';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be like this

```
<div class="btn btn-success">
    <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a>           
    <? else: ?>
        <?php add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false ); ?><?php endif; ?>            
</div>
```

Comment: You appear to have left an extra curly brace near `endif`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. Try this code

```
<div class="btn btn-success">   
    <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $submit_question_link ?>"<?php _e('Ask a question','dwqa') ?></a> 
    <?php else:
        add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login to Ask a Question', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false );
        endif;
    ?>         
</div>
```

Comment: Thank all of so much. However I tried everyones new code and all I get is the white screen. However the code here works..<?php
     if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
         echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
     } else {
         echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
     }
     ?>